# Converting Subgurim GMap Coordinates to string

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, coordinates, subgurim-maps

I have started using `Subgurim's Map` controls for `ASP.NET` and need to convert the `coordinates` into a `string` or something similar so that I can put it in my `database`.

Here is my code:

> ```
>     Protected Sub lnkShowMap_Click(ByVal sender As Object,
>     ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lnkShowMap.Click
>     Dim strFullAddress As String
>     Dim sMapKey As String =
>     ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("googlemaps.subgurim.net")
>     Dim GeoCode As Subgurim.Controles.GeoCode
>
>     ' Combine our address fields to create the full address.  The street,
>     ' suburb and country should be seperated by  periods (.)
>     strFullAddress = txtStreetAddress.Text & ". " & txtSuburb.Text & ". " & txtCountry.Text
>
>     ' Work out the longitude and latitude
>     GeoCode = GMap1.geoCodeRequest(strFullAddress, sMapKey)
> Dim gLatLng As New Subgurim.Controles.GLatLng(GeoCode.Placemark.coordinates.lat,
>     GeoCode.Placemark.coordinates.lng)
>     ' Display the map
>     GMap1.setCenter(gLatLng, 16, Subgurim.Controles.GMapType.GTypes.Normal)
>     Dim oMarker As New Subgurim.Controles.GMarker(gLatLng)
>     GMap1.addGMarker(oMarker)
>
>     ' Create coordinates in stored mem ' 
>     Dim coordinates As GeoCode = GMap1.getGeoCodeRequest(GeoCode.Placemark.coordinates)
>     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(coordinates)
> End Sub
> ```

I'm having a problem with the last two lines of this `sub`, I am defining `'coordinates'` as being the result of `Gmap1's placemarker's coordinates`, but despite the fact that during `debugging`, the value of `GeoCode.Placemark.coordinates` is not being attributed to `'coordinates'`

Here is a screenshot of the `debugging process`:
http://www.wherelionsroam.co.uk/debug.png

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you call `GMap1.getGeoCodeRequest()` passing a `GLatLng` object as a parameter you will waste a geocoding call because the returned coordinates will be the same you passed as an argument. Actually, in you code you have all you need in `GeoCode.Placemark.coordinates`.

```
Dim coordinates as GLatLng = GeoCode.Placemark.coordinates
```

The in the coordinates variable you'll have the `lat` and `lng` properties with the information you need and saving one geocoding call (it's important to save calls because they are limited by Google).